# Extract all values from data in JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have a [json](/questions/tagged/json) response with multiple movie titles in `"data"`. Is there a way to quickly extract them? I need an array with just movie titles.

```
{
  "page": "2",
  "per_page": 10,
  "total": 13,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "data": [{
    "Poster": "N/A",
    "Title": "They Call Me Spiderman",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Year": 2016,
    "imdbID": "tt5861236"
  }, {
    "Poster": "N/A",
    "Title": "The Death of Spiderman",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Year": 2015,
    "imdbID": "tt5921428"
  }, {
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZDlmMGQwYmItNTNmOS00OTNkLTkxNTYtNDM3ZWVlMWUyZDIzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTA5Mzk5Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Title": "Spiderman in Cannes",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Year": 2016,
    "imdbID": "tt5978586"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Json.NET? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [newtonsoft](/questions/tagged/newtonsoft).
- C# [System.dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic).
- C# [ExpandoObject Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

In this way:

```
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(data);
```

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string data = @"{
  'page': '2',
  'per_page': 10,
  'total': 13,
  'total_pages': 2,
  'data': [{
    'Poster': 'N/A',
    'Title': 'They Call Me Spiderman',
    'Type': 'movie',
    'Year': 2016,
    'imdbID': 'tt5861236'
  }, {
    'Poster': 'N/A',
    'Title': 'The Death of Spiderman',
    'Type': 'movie',
    'Year': 2015,
    'imdbID': 'tt5921428'
  }, {
    'Poster': 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZDlmMGQwYmItNTNmOS00OTNkLTkxNTYtNDM3ZWVlMWUyZDIzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTA5Mzk5Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg',
    'Title': 'Spiderman in Cannes',
    'Type': 'movie',
    'Year': 2016,
    'imdbID': 'tt5978586'
  }]
}";
        dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(data);
        int i;
        int len = content.data.Count;
        string result = "";
        string[] myArray;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            result += content.data[i].Title; // Extract the movie title.
            result += ","; // Conact with commas.
        }

        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
        myArray = result.Split(','); // Array of string with the movie titles.
        Console.WriteLine(myArray[0]);
    }
}
```

See in action: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kZY2I).

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data.Add("foo", "baa"); 

JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var JSONString = ser.Serialize(data); //JSON encoded

var JSONObj = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(JSONString); //JSON decoded
Console.Write(JSONObj["foo"]); //prints: baa
```

Comment: Danny, thank you. But the question was how to do it in C#, not JavaScript (see tags). I apologize for not writing it more clearly

Comment: Sorry about that. Take a look at newtonsoft.json https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm

Answer (score 0):

using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` might do the simplest work for you.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

List<string> movieTitles = (JObject.Parse(json)["data"]).
                   Cast<JToken>().Select(x => x["Title"].ToString()).ToList();
```